# MySQL UPDATE one table with multiple rows from another table to change misspelled words using REGEXP word boundaries

Tags: mysql, regex, join

I want to update job_titles_table with the spelling corrections in the misspelled_words_table.

```
** job_titles_table **                               ** misspelled_words_table **
job_title_id    job_title                            job_title_id  misspelled_word   correct_spelling
15802           animation dept superviser            15802         animation         Animation
15803           animator / character key assistant   15802         dept              Department
15804           Lead 2D Animator                     15802         superviser        Supervisor
15805           Character Technical Director         15803         animator          Animator
15806           character layout apprentice          15803         assistant         Assistant
15807           Production Coordinator               15803         key               Key
15808           lighting and render engineer         15806         apprentice        Apprentice
                                                     15806         layout            Layout
                                                     15808         engineer          Engineer
                                                     15808         lighting          Lighting
                                                     15808         render            Render
```

This query…

```
UPDATE job_titles_table j
RIGHT JOIN misspelled_words_table t USING (j.job_title_id)
SET j.job_title = REPLACE(j.job_title,t.misspelled_word,t.correct_spelling)
```

Yields the results below. Notice ‘Department’ and ‘Supervisor’ aren’t changed in 15802, Only ‘Animation’ is changed.

```
** job_titles_table **
job_title_id    job_title
15802           Animation dept superviser
15803           Animator / character key assistant
15804           Lead 2D Animator
15805           Character Technical Director
15806           character layout Apprentice
15807           Production Coordinator
15808           lighting and render Engineer
```

Comment: if you have more words to replace you must repeat the query more  time ..or use a store procedure  .. or use a proceural approach with a server side language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UPDATE is not applying changes cumulatively. Each change is applied to the original `j.job_title` string. Notice in each case, exactly one word has been fixed, but which word is unpredictable. For example, in 15806, "Apprentice" has been fixed, but not "layout".

I'd say you're not going to be able to use this technique to do all the replacements in a single joined UPDATE statement.

The best way to do this in standard SQL would be to write a cursor loop, but unfortunately MySQL doesn't support `UPDATE WHERE CURRENT OF CURSOR`.

One straightforward workaround would be to use a SELECT joining the tables together and the output of the SELECT would be a string which is a fully-formed UPDATE statement.

```
SELECT CONCAT( 
  'UPDATE job_titles_table SET job_title = REPLACE(job_title, ',
  QUOTE(t.misspelled_word), ', ',
  QUOTE(t.correct_spelling),
  ') WHERE job_title_id = ', t.job_title_id, ';'
) AS _sql
FROM misspelled_words_table t;
```

The output should be a series of strings like:

```
UPDATE job_titles_table SET job_title = REPLACE(job_title, 'animation', 'Animation') WHERE job_title_id = 15802;
UPDATE job_titles_table SET job_title = REPLACE(job_title, 'department', 'Department') WHERE job_title_id = 15802;
```

Loop over the result of the SELECT and execute each UPDATE as a dynamic SQL statement.

P.S.: You're using `RIGHT JOIN` where you should be using `INNER JOIN`. It does no harm in this case, but you might want to read up about join types so you use the proper type.

Comment: Here is what I ended up doing...

`SELECT concat('UPDATE job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(job_title,''',s.misspelled_word,''',''',s.correct_spelling,''')',' WHERE job_title_id = ', job_title_id,';') AS SQL_UPDATE_STATEMENT
FROM common_misspellings AS s
JOIN job_title AS j
WHERE j.job_title REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',replace(s.misspelled_word,'.','[[.period.]]'),'[[:>:]]')
`

Comment: You're using LOWER() in every update, and your correction is to capitalize the words. So each update re-lowercases the title that was capitalized on the previous statement.

Comment: I added a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594873/updating-the-same-column-in-the-same-row-multiple-times-with-mysql-update

I added the lower() because I wanted to ignore case in job_title. I'd like to be able to have greensWoman to be changed to Greenswoman. How do I ignore case when using replace()?

Comment: I have posted an answer on that other question.

Answer (score 0):

So... the single quotes in the misspelled words started causing trouble... So this is the new query...
`SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(job_title,''',
               REPLACE(s.misspelled_word,char(39),CONCAT(char(39),char(39))),''',''',
               REPLACE(s.correct_spelling,char(39),CONCAT(char(39),char(39))),''')',
               ' WHERE job_title_id = ', job_title_id,';') AS sql_update_statement
FROM     common_misspellings AS s
JOIN     job_title           AS j
WHERE    j.job_title REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',REPLACE(s.misspelled_word,'.','[[.period.]]'),'[[:>:]]')`