# Updating the same column in the same row multiple times with MySQL UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to change all the words in the `job_title`.

In my example below the `job_title` is:

`art department work experience/greenswoman` in row `86619`.

Here is the code:

`Set autocommit = 1;`

`UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'art','Art') WHERE job_title_id = 86619;
UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'work','Work') WHERE job_title_id = 86619;
UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'department','Department') WHERE job_title_id = 86619;
UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'experience','Experience') WHERE job_title_id = 86619;
UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'greenswoman','Greenswoman') WHERE job_title_id = 86619;`

`select job_title from tvt_job_title where job_title_id = 86619;`

The result:

`art department work experience/Greenswoman`  **only Greenswoman gets corrected!**  Why don't all the words get corrected?

The output:

`UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'art','Art') WHERE job_title_id = 86619  1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0`

`UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'work','Work') WHERE job_title_id = 86619    1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0`

`UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'department','Department') WHERE job_title_id = 86619    1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0`

`UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'experience','Experience'), abbreviation = REPLACE(LOWER(abbreviation),'experience','Experience') WHERE job_title_id = 86619 1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0`

`UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = REPLACE(LOWER(job_title),'greenswoman','Greenswoman'), abbreviation = REPLACE(LOWER(abbreviation),'greenswoman','Greenswoman') WHERE job_title_id = 86619 1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0`

`select job_title from tvt_job_title where job_title_id = 86619 1 row(s) returned`

Comment: It looks like you're specifically filtering everything to `job_title_id = 86619`.  Would that happen to be the `job_title_id` for "Greenswoman"?

Comment: Yes.  I want to change all the words in the column job_title for row 86619.  LOWER() is the cause of the trouble here.  I was trying to do a case insensitive REPLACE so that greensWoman would change to Greenswoman.  The result I want is 'Art Department Work Experience/Greenswoman'

Comment: Ah ... that makes sense.  You're updating multiple values in a single field, not multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is caused by the `LOWER(job_title)` function call in the update statements because it converts the entire job title lowercase, therefore eradicates the changes done by any previous updates in your code. You have to remove the `lower()` function from the code.

```
UPDATE tvt_job_title SET job_title = 
REPLACE(job_title,'work','Work') WHERE job_title_id = 86619
```

Comment: I added the lower() because I wanted to ignore case in job_title.  I'd like to be able to have greensWoman to be changed to Greenswoman. How do I ignore case when using replace()?

Comment: If you have a follow-up question, then pls ask it as a new question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's REPLACE() function is not case-insensitive.

I found this blog about a user who created a stored function to do case-insensitive string replace. It's awkward. https://pento.net/2009/02/15/case-insensitive-replace-for-mysql/

For this task, if you have special string comparison requirements, you might find it easier to just write a script to do it one row at a time.